# overlay a small image on multiple biger images and save them in a different folder

Tags: opencv, python

Hi i want to overlay or paste an image on bigger images(have a folder containinf 10 images and want to overlay the smaller images on all 10) and save them in a different folder. I did try somethings but ran into errors.

```
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

outPath = "C:\darkflow\Augmented Images\augmented_images\.."

cov = cv2.imread("C:\darkflow\Augmented Images\extracted\cover\extracted_cover.jpg")
bgs  = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\darkflow\Augmented Images\images\*.jpg")]

for bg in bgs:    
    bg[y_offset:y_offset+s_img.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+s_img.shape[1]] = cov

    f_image = cv2.cvtColor(bg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    fullpath = os.path.join(outPath, 'augmented_'+ bg)

    misc.imsave(fullpath, f_image)
```

with this code i get an error : ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while looking into the code. My code is

```
from scipy import ndimage, misc
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2



cov = cv2.imread("C:\darkflow\Augmented Images\extracted\cover\extracted_cover.jpg")
bgs  = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\darkflow\Augmented Images\images\*.jpg")]
d=1
x_offset=100
y_offset= 100
for bg in bgs:    
    bg[y_offset:y_offset+ cov.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+ cov.shape[1]] = cov
    filename =  "images/file_%d.jpg"%d
    cv2.imwrite(filename, bg)
    d+=1
```